# Two eps files merged into one with them side-by-side: How?

Tags: linux, image-processing, eps

How can I combining two EPS files side-by-side on Linux? What is the command to use?

Comment: [Combining multiple .eps files into a single figure](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/84889)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your response, but that's a TeX solution. I would like a more UNIX style solution. TeXLive is fairly large to install and is often not unavaible.